# angular - ui-router - directive - get offset/position of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, angular-directive

I've had this issue with many projects using angular and ui-router.

I have a directive, and I simply want to get its size/position or the  size/position  of its containing element.  In my directive, which is rendered in a ui-router view, I've attached a controller, and when I try to get the size, however, it's always zero.

```
element.position() -> Object {top: 0, left: 0}
element.offset() -> Object {top: 0, left: 0}
```

in my directive I have this:

```
templateUrl: 'some-html-file',
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, someController) {
    someController.init(elem);
}
```

in `someController`

```
this.init = function (element) {
     $scope.element = element;
     console.log($scope.element.position());
     console.log($scope.element.offset());
}
```

Im not sure how I can get the position and size of my directive.  Are there any ideas?  is this related to ui-router or maybe this is related to angular using a directive?  I'm guessing its a timeing issue - trying to get info on the dom before angular is finished with the dom?  any help appreciated!

Comment: Create a demo that replicates this. Not really enough known about the html structure or css or even how elements are rendered. Can easily be zero if it's still hidden for example .. hidden elements have no dimensions or offset

Comment: @charlietfl ok i'll try to drum up a plunker

Answer (score 1):

Such style-related routines need to be postponed. Some things didn't happen when `link` ran (first of all, child's `link` [precedes](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/) its parent). And usually you have to do

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, someController) {
    $timeout(function () {
        someController.init(elem);
    });
}
```

Likewise, other directives will postpone some things to the next digest, and occasionally you need `$timeout` with non-zero delay to make it work.

Comment: another helpful trick is using `$last` property in an `ng-repeat` to trigger dom manipulation if repeater is involved

Comment: @estus good idea - its not working.  I also cannot repeat the issue in my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6YiJPlJJCmQ0whyQqWcB?p=preview  There must be something else weird going on.  drats!  i'll see if i can get plunker to have the same error.

Comment: @estus - I couldn't get plunker to respect the bootstrap styling.  maybe its related to that?

Comment: @Tucker It may depend on a lot of things, both styling and contents. Anyway, `$timeout(..., 200)` hasn't failed me in such cases. You may also want to have additional DOM listeners because of resize, dimensions change, etc.

Comment: @charlietfl Sure. Ironically, ng-repeat is among guilty ones IIRC, it relies on scope watchers and is completely initialized after link.